# Creating contracts between React front-end and C# back-end?

Tags: c#, reactjs, rest, datacontract

I consider myself to be pretty well-versed in C#, but with React / Typescript I'm a relative beginner. One thing which I liked about pure C# projects is that my front-end and back-end can both be based off of the same object model, which means when I make an API call to the back-end, I can be sure that the object I'm passing from the front-end corresponds to the object I'm expecting to receive on the back-end.

Does something like this exist with React / Typescript? The project I'm working with, as-written, has an ApiModel.ts file (which is ostensibly auto-generated) that contains the models for the objects I'm passing - but to me, this feels like a weakly-typed setup. Other than a friendly warning message at the top of the file, there is nothing preventing me from modifying the ApiModel.ts file to add properties that are not present on the receiving end (which, presumably, would either cause an error or be handled internally).

Basically - tl;dr, is there any way for me to validate, at compile time, that the API model on the React side properly matches the API model on the C# side?

Comment: *Does something like this exist with React / Typescript?* -sure; your c# back end oublishes a swagger/openapi spec, and then some tooling for the front end consumes it and generates say, a bunch of TS

Comment: This is essentially what that ApiModel.ts file is - guessing it is generated by swagger or etc. But that in-between step, of generating the ApiModel.ts file, is what I'm disliking - there's no guarantee that the model you have, is the correct one. If the back-end api model changes, and you don't regenerate the model on the front-end, then things will break. Basically - what I want is, when I build the front-end to launch in debug mode, I want to be able to validate that the api model is correct.

Comment: I don't know how you'd do it for your tooling, but I'm currently on with a C# net core back end that effectively generates a swagger.json every time it's built, and the front end code (also C# as it happens, in VS, using NSwag) downloads it every time *it* does a build, and NSwag regenerates the stubs, so the moment a back end change means the swagger changes it reflects in the front end generated code, possibly even causing a build error if existing code uses something tthat changed.. Take a look at your tooling to see what it can do in a similar fashion; autorest CLI does TS and takes a URL